# Release Substitution Inheritance of Json Variables

Tags: azure-devops

I currently use Azure-Devops to build and release my codebase to multiple environments and have a question on the Release Aspect.

I have multiple URL's in my `appSettings.json` which point to different API Endpoints for example(in local):

IDSrvr4 Login is `https://localhost:5001`.
IDSrvr4 Post logout is `https://localhost:5001/logout`.
Health Checks `https://localhost:5001/healthz`.

is there a way for me to configure the Release Variables so that, i have:

```
baseWebsite:https://dev.environemnt.com
idSrvr4.loginRedirect:$(baseWebsite)
idSrvr4.postLogutRedirect:$(baseWebsite)/logout
healthChecks.Uri: $(baseWebsite)/healthz
```

so that i have one location to change the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add baseWebsite to the Variables tab of your release definition and set it's value to https://dev.environemnt.com you can use a task like Patch JSON Files to replace the values in your appSettings.json.  You might need to install the Patch JSON Files task from the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-file-patch&targetId=37794dd8-bc1d-45e3-9aba-63be06ab065e&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList)

Once it's installed configure the Patch JSON Files task similar to below (your Patch Content might be slightly different depending on the structure of your appSettings.json, this is my best guess based on the snippet you've provided).

[image: Patch JSON Files config]

You can then set a different value in the Variables tab for baseWebsite for each environment, as long as the Patch JSON Files task has been added to agent job for that environment the values in appSettings.json will get replaced with the value for that environment